# Manual injection of producer data

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

## Question

I am working with support of legacy data and some multi-functional implementations.  I am able to easily inject fully managed bean instances using basic code such as this:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup(BEAN_MANAGER_JNDI_NAME);
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(beanClass);
Bean bean = beanManager.getBeans(beanClass).iterator().next();
CreationalContext creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
T managedInstance = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, beanClass, creationalContext);
```

However, in the case of wanting to inject data from `@Producer` implementations, it does not work.

Using the classic example:

```
@Produces
@LoggerType
public Logger getLogger (InjectionPoint) { ... }
```

In my class this does not get resolved:

```
@Inject
@LoggerType
Logger log;
```

My **workaround** is just getting a completely managed instance of the class I am working in and then copying things in the following manner:

```
MyType managedInstance = CdiUtilities.getManagedInstance(getClass());
this.log = managedInstance.log;
```

How would I accomplish this?
Is there something I need to do to get the `@Producer` data registered?

## Details

I'm deploying on Wildly using:

- jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools (1.0.0.M1)
- javax.servlet-api (3.1.0)
- javax cdi-api
- jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec
- jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec

Qualifier is pretty pathetically simple:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target ({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface LoggerType { }
```

Comment: Does the application server throws an exception when you use the classic example? How does your code of qualifier @LoggerType looks like?

Comment: Please also indicate what implementation of CDI you're using, version, etc.

Comment: Added information above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take things in the order.

You're deploying to WildFly, so your target is Java EE 7 and CDI 1.1 (WildFly 8.0.0 and 8.1.0) or CDI 1.2 (WildFly 8.2.0).

In all case you can simplify your lookup code like this:

```
    BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    Bean bean = beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(beanClass));
    CreationalContext creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    T managedInstance = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, beanClass, creationalContext);
```

You don't give a lot of information of how you use this code. Just keep in mind that there might be nicer way of integrating your legacy code than this one...

Regarding your producer issue. I see 4 possible reason for this problem.

1. you are using `@javax.ws.rs.Produces` instead of `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`. Check the import section of the class file containing your producer.
2. You are in an [implicit bean archive or the bean discovery mode of your archive is `annotated`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive) and the bean containing your producer don't have a [bean defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations). Add @Dependent on the class that contains the producer.
3. The class containing your producer [doesn't meet the conditions to be a bean](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#what_classes_are_beans). Check that you can inject this bean.
4. Your war contains Java EE jars provided by WildFly and this cause unpredictable behaviour. Check your `WEB-INF/lib` to see if one of the lib you mentioned above wasn't packaged with your app (they should be scoped as provided in Maven).

BTW you should use Java EE 7 dependency to compile your code since you're deploying to WildFly.

Comment: Got things working.

1. Verified
2. Switched things around and got that working - **this was the problem**
3. Verified
4. Verified

Now, I just need to fix the `InjectionPoint` problem and I'm all good.
It looks like I need to reevaluate my understanding of that 2nd note.

Comment: FYI - I updated to the EE7 dependency as well after verifying other things worked.  I was unaware of that as a "should" for Wildfly, but it is something I know to keep my eye on now as well.

Comment: Even better - I was completely ignoring [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org).

Comment: Yes DS is a great solution to enhance your CDI development. Regarding EE 7 dependency for Wildfly, it's not mandatory (EE 6 app runs on it) but it's better to have access to all the new API in EE 7